# How to prevent terminal from opening automatically when resizing output panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to resize the output panel using the mouse, the terminal pops up on its own. How to prevent this annoying behaviour?

The output panel is for the Arduino extension by Microsoft.

Example GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No reproducible with my VS Code.
Try to change some of the extension settings
like arduino.useArduinoCli, "Analyse on setting change" or others.
The behavior seems not being spotted in the Issues in GitHub :
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues